# Chromebook, Ubuntu and Second Life

Tags: games, chromebook

Alright so I'm a long term Windows user. My computer died and i had to fall back onto a Beta Chromebook with Chrome OS. now I have already used a youtube video to install Linux/Ubuntu/Unity with crouton.

Now I just need help downloading my favorite game Second Life (preferable with the Firestorm Viewer). Now unless it wasn't already obvious I know nothing about Linux/Ubuntu so I could really use a start to finish/step by step instruction manual.

I work better with youtube videos if someone is willing to make me one. When I say start to finish I mean it: every update and application from the installation of Ubuntu to the start up of the game.

Comment: You should consider learning some linux first, rather than SL. After all, you most probably learned some Windows before learning SL.

Answer (score 1):

To install second life on ubuntu follow these steps.

- First of all download tarball of game from here  [Second_Life_3_7_24_297623_i686.tar.bz2](http://download.cloud.secondlife.com/Viewer_3/Second_Life_3_7_24_297623_i686.tar.bz2).
- Save it to your home folder(`/home/YOUR USERNAME`).
- Right click the downloaded file and open with archive manager,
- select option `extract here.`
- Fire up a terminal.(On your keyboard: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>-)
- Change Directory by running : `cd Second_Life_3_7_24_297623_i686`
- Then in the same terminal: `sudo ./install.sh`,

  - It will ask for your password, so type your password, press enter,
  - press enter again
- If everything goes fine than Go to dash and type secondlife and click on second life icon to play.

Hope it helps

Comment: well i tried this up down and sideways. the OS seems to try and start up the installed application but crashes before the window opens am i missing something? some minor or even major thing?

Comment: Are you getting any error message after windows crahses.

Comment: only when i try to start it with the terminal

Comment: @BlueHaste Then please post the error message. Also, Chromebooks have too low-spec hardware to run games, I think.

Answer (score -1):

I have heard that SL needs to run in 32 bit mode on Linux, and that this requires getting and installing the necessary 32 bit drivers. I don't know how reliable the source is, but if you've tried everything else and it still doesn't work, what have you got to lose??

Comment: Your answer does not seem to be dealing with the OPs question. Could you please stick to the question.